# iOS - UILabel + UIActivityIndicatorView inside UITableView section header

Tags: iphone, ios

In the Settings app when you select a Wi-Fi network you can see a table view that has a label and an activity indicator right after the label. Is there some predefined way to create such a UI. Or the only way to do it is to implement the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` with some code that creates a label and a spinner, calculates the label width and places the spinner right after it?

Comment: @CodaFi how is that in any way related to the post you identified as a dupe? (despite the keyword WiFi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have the right approach! Create a header view with a label and place an UIActivityIndicator right after it. The calculation is pretty simple:

```
UILabel* myLabel = ...;
CGSize size = [myLabel.text sizeWithFont: myLabel.font];

UIActivityIndicator* indicatorView = ...;
indicatorView.center = CGPointMake(size.width + indicatorView.frame.size.width, myLabel.center.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell.accessoryView, create a UIActivityIndicator instance and assign to it.

Comment: The OP asks for putting the Activity Indicator in Section Header, not in a Tableviewcell